# Предотвращение засыпания во время выполнения

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

Как можно запретить отключение дисплея/засыпание/переход в ждущий режим или гибернацию ПК во время выполнения программы?

На ПК установлены следующие настройки схемы электропитания:
Отключение дисплея: 5 мин
Сон: 10 мин

```
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);
```

почему то все равно позволяет отключение дисплея.

Доп вопрос, не смог нагуглить, получает ли приложение какое-либо сообщение от системы (типа WM_***) перед тем, как система собирается заснуть?

Comment: Асоциация http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494989/preventing-sleep-mode

Comment: Вот это вроде оно http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629240/prevent-windows-from-going-into-sleep-when-my-program-is-running/16086508#16086508

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо, видел через PowerSerRequest, но хочется одной строкой, вдруг кто расскажет что не так)

Comment: Там ниже ответ зеленой галочкой лучше. http://stackoverflow.com/a/629286/5727271 Одной строкой не выйдет, разве что какой-то фреймворк хороший:)

Comment: для дисплея же отдельный флаг: `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED`